# Get JSON from self hosted wordpress site

Tags: json, plugin-json-api

I am very new to wordpress so this may seem basic.

I have a ***NON-WordPress*** website in which I would like to consume various blogs (via category/tags etc etc) from my **WordPress** site.

**Currently I am using this plugin:**
http://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-json/

- Although it works fine, sadly it seems to only return the latest 10 blog entries (0-9) which does not cover all the data I want to interact with.
- I have looked at the documentation for this plugin but I cannot see any way of changing how many entries to return.

I have seen this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

- Would that plugin solve my problem?
- Is it likely to cause conflicts having two JSON type plugins running at the same time?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Wordpress setting you can change. Login to the WP admin panel, click Settings > Reading, change "Syndication feed show the most recent" from the default 10 items to something higher, and click Save. If you don't see the change immediately, try clearing the recent cache in your browser, or open the link in a different browser.

Comment: Perfect! That seems to have done the trick. Thank you for this. I would +1 you but I dont have the ability yet. Its a shame someone has given me a -1 on this without passing comment. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad that worked and welcome to WPSE. The reason someone down voted is probably because questions about third party plugins or themes are considered off-topic. While your question seems to be about a plugin, the answer lies in the Wordpress core, but I'm not really sure where that leaves it as far as on or off topic; I added an up vote to balance out the -1 though.

Comment: Thank you for doing that. Much appreciated. I have inherited a wordpress site which I have little knowledge on so suspect I will be asking quite a lot on here. :)